# How to combine .each with .not()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some checkboxes and I'm trying to make an invert function, but I want to affect all but the first checkbox, so I'm using jQuery and after a research I understood I should use .not(':first'), but I don't know where to put it in the code I have already written.

```
function invert(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
$(this).prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});}
```

Would you help me, please?

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:first)')`?

Comment: yes, this also works, sorry but I'm new in jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, including but not limited to the following.

All in the selector:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:first)').each(...)
```

With the [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':first').each(...)
```

With the [`.slice()` method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').slice(1).each(...)
```

Note that the line that actually checks/unchecks the boxes can be simplified to this:

```
this.checked = !this.checked;
```

But if the only thing you are doing in the loop is changing the checked property then you don't need `.each()`, you can instead [pass a function to `prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:first)').prop("checked", function(i, val) {
    return !val;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `:gt()` selector with paramter `0` to select elements having index greater than `0` : first

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:gt(0)").each(function() {
  // do stuff with `input` elements having index greater than `0`
})
```